# 2 -level pick list on salesforce list 1 dependent on list 2.

Tags: visualforce, administration

I have two pick lists as custom fields in the Account section. I want one to be dependent on another. Those lists look like this.

[image: list1]
[image: list2]
[image: list3]

I want the 2 first lists to look like the 3rd one. I've read that you need to set field dependencies but I'm not sure how to do that.

Comment: here is the example https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.fundamentals.meta/fundamentals/adg_simple_app_adv_field_dependencies_try_it_out.htm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Try It Out: Create a Dependent Picklist**

Looking at the picklists that we've created, it's quickly obvious that our users might get frustrated with the length of our Job Level picklist. Let's make our users happy by turning Job Level into a dependent field of the Functional Area picklist. Doing this will allow users to see only the four relevant job level values when a department is selected in the Functional Area picklist:

1. From Setup, enter Objects in the Quick Find box, then select **Objects**.
2. Click **Position**.
3. In the Custom Fields & Relationships related list, click **Field Dependencies**.
4. Click **New**.
5. For the Controlling Field drop-down list, choose Functional Area.
6. For the Dependent Field drop-down list, choose Job Level.
7. Click **Continue**.

A field dependency matrix displays with all the values in the controlling field across the top header row and the dependent field values listed in the columns below.

For each possible value of the controlling field, we need to include the values that should be displayed in the dependent picklist when that controlling value is selected. In the field dependency matrix, yellow highlighting shows which dependent field values are included in the picklist for a particular controlling field value.

To include a dependent field value, you simply double-click it. To exclude a dependent value from the list, double-click it again.

For example, let's try it out by including the values that should be displayed in the Job Level picklist whenever Finance is selected in the Functional Area picklist:

8. In the column labeled Finance, double-click FN-100, FN-200, FN-300, and FN-400.

Fore info https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.fundamentals.meta/fundamentals/adg_simple_app_adv_field_dependencies_try_it_out.htm

[image]